# With scrapy, perform an action in a pipeline, for every n items scraped

Tags: python, scrapy

After every time that a fixed number of scraped items in a scrapy pipeline has been processed, I'd like to perform a certain action. For example, after every 100 items, a database commit should be performed. Is there a recommended way to do this with scrapy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scrapy [Pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html).
in `pipelines.py`:

```
class MyPipeline:
    count = 0
    def process_item(self, item, spider)
        count += 1
        if count == 100:
            count = 0 
            # do something
```

and activate it in your `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'mypackage.pipelines.MyPipeline': 100
}
```

Comment: This will perform the required action after doing 100 loop iterations per item, not once per 100 items. I'd like to perform an action once per 100 (or whatever number) items scraped. I edited the title of the question, in case the original was unclear.

Comment: @Boa No, `process_item` is called for every item is returned by the spider. So every 100th item will perform the action.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, I misread your code. You're right - this should do. Thanks!

Comment: @Boa no problem at all :)